# Springboot Application background image not loading

Tags: css, spring-boot, jsp

I'm trying to add a background image to the jsp page in my springboot application.

My file structure is like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9msWn.jpg)

My css file is like this:

```
header {
    background-image: url(images/img1.jpg); 
    margin: 0; 
    
    height: 100vh; 
    
}
```

However, the picture is not loading. When I run my application. The header background is all black. Where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. It's because the image size is too big (i.e. about 3- 4 Mb). When I reduce the image size to 60-70KB, they are displaying properly.